# node.js error when parsing lesscss from php (Symfony2 Assetic)

Tags: node.js, symfony, less, assetic

I have just set up lesscss with NPM on Centos5 and am using it within a Symfony2 php app.

If I run on commandline

```
less mycssfile.less
```

then it parses fine and I get the correctly parsed output in console.

But within the Symfony2 app as a filter in the Assetic bundle, the css file is just a 500 error.

Looking in the log it is producing the following error:

```
request.CRITICAL: RuntimeException: FATAL ERROR: v8::Context::New() V8 is no longer usable
```

Im fairly sure the Symfony2 elements are set up ok as the project, including the config for lesscss, is part of a git repo that checks out and works fine with no errors elsewhere.

EDIT /

Additional info - I've just installed node so it's at the latest version.

EDIT /

Running less on the command line works fine, and running less in a shell_exec() in a php script through the web browser works fine.

Comment: I'd recommend trying an older version of Node to rule out that it's not just a bug in V8.

Comment: Dropped back to 0.5.9 but still the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is \`node.js\` dying when called from inside python/uwsgi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725168/why-is-node-js-dying-when-called-from-inside-python-uwsgi)