# Why is `node.js` dying when called from inside python/uwsgi?

Tags: python, node.js, wsgi, uwsgi, subprocess

From the shell this `python` code which start and communicates with a `node.js` process works fine:

```
> from subprocess import *
> js = "(function(m) { console.log(m) })('hello world')"
> (out,err) = Popen(["node"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False).communicate(js)
> out
"hello world\n"
```

But when I run the same code from within [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) I instead get this in `err`:

`'FATAL ERROR: v8::Context::New() V8 is no longer usable\n'`

Any insights from either the `wsgi` community or the `node.js` community? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Might have something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131700/python-subprocess-popen-slow-under-uwsgi

Comment: @LinusGThiel I haven't tried the uwsgi setting change yet but the python based suggestion for calling `Popen` with `close_fds=True` didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you are running uWSGI with memory constraints (like --limit-as or a cgroup/jail). Processes spawned from it will inherit those limits. Even check for environment variables v8 could expect (like HOME)

Comment: Increasing the uwsgi per-process memory limit fixed it! The setting was: `<limit-as>512</limit-as>` and I upped it to `<limit-as>768</limit-as>`